# Using update command in Switch statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, switch-statement

I am trying to use and update command in switch case statement but when i run it, it is not updating at all, not sure what am i doing wrong here.  Here is my code:

```
protected void update()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand Mycmd = new SqlCommand();       
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name, Stage from Mytable  WHERE ID=  @ID ", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", (ID));
    da.Fill(dt); 

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        switch (Convert.ToString(row["Stage"]))
        {
            case "1":                    
                string myStage= txtStageLevel.Text;
                Mycmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Mytable SET Stage=@myStage";
                break;
        }
```

Comment: So where is the code where you call `Mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: also missing the part where you actually add `@myStage` as parameter ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the ExecuteNonQuery call, the setting of the parameter @myStage and the Connection is not assigned to the command. After all this probably you would change your code to

```
case "1":
    using(SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Mytable SET Stage=@myStage", con)
    {
       myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myStage", txtStageLevel.Text);
       myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    break;
```

And remove the declaration of MyCmd at the beginning of the method.

Finally, open the connection explicitily in the code before entering the switch case....

Comment: I downvoted because in the beginning you put in a placeholder answer that should have been a comment.

Comment: Fine, I have noticed immediately the lacking of ExecuteNonQuery and this is hardly a comment. However other problems emerged and now (in the five minutes timing) I have all explained them